# Get only the id that has more than one start date before the end date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I made this select and got these values. I need to get only the ones that for some reason have a start date twice or more before the end date (example: the first one, if you look at the first two rows)

```
     id       id        Start Date                End Date
    33730   33730   01/02/2012 12:00:00 AM  13/11/2012 12:00:00 AM
    33730   33730   26/10/2012 12:00:00 AM  13/11/2012 12:00:00 AM
    33732   33732   01/02/2012 12:00:00 AM  01/10/2013 12:00:00 AM
    33732   33732   05/08/2013 12:00:00 AM  01/10/2013 12:00:00 AM
    33744   33744   02/02/2012 12:00:00 AM  12/04/2012 12:00:00 AM
    33744   33744   13/03/2012 12:00:00 AM  12/04/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

This is my initial query

```
   select ENTRADA.nro_referencia as id1, SALIDA.NRO_REFERENCIA as id2, ENTRADA.FECHA_ENTRADA as Start_Date, SALIDA.FECHA_SALIDA as End_Date
   FROM ENTRADA LEFT JOIN SALIDA on ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA = SALIDA.NRO_REFERENCIA
    where FECHA_ENTRADA < '1/1/2014' AND
   ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA in 
   (select dbo.ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA from ENTRADA where FECHA_ENTRADA < FECHA_SALIDA group by dbo.ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA having count(*) > 1)
   order by dbo.ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA
```

Comment: Will there ever be more than one distinct end date per `id`?

Comment: `SELECT id, MIN(StartDate), EndDate FROM mytable GROUP BY id, EndDate` ?

Comment: No cause I basically compared both ids, I was planning on touching the query later so i can get the full left join but for something else

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of ID's which have the start date before the end date at least twice:

```
SELECT id
  FROM myTable
  WHERE StartDate < EndDate
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

You can use it with an `IN` clause to filter your main query:

```
SELECT id, StartDate, EndDate
FROM myTable
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
    FROM myTable
    WHERE StartDate < EndDate
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2)
```

Comment: This is fine and it's what I basically do in my initial select. But maybe my example wasn't that good, lets say I have one id with 10/10 start and 15/10 end and then the same id below with 16/10 start and 17/10 end.  This is fine cause it's supposed to have 1 entry, 1 exit. But like in my initial examples in my table sometimes i have 2 starts before an end. I want to filter only those ones

Comment: No problem. Would the second and third IDs also be part of the results? If not, try to explain why; that might help clarify what you need.

Comment: Not really as long as the first id is there It's fine. I made that select left joining two tables (one has start dates and ID and the other one end date and ID, and ofc they share same id), because I need to do more things with this select but this one is the hardest.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend posting the original query (or at least a simplified version), samples from the two tables, and an explanation of why certain IDs would be included or excluded. It'll be harder but you'll be more likely to get a good answer. Additionally, rather than update this question I'd delete it and post another because newer questions will get more views - most likely a lot of folks looked at this question, thought "not enough information", and moved on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you records where the same id had two separate start dates before the first one's end date, but not sure if this is how you want the output organized:

```
with cte as (
select row_number over (partition by ENTRADA.nro_referencia order by SALIDA.FECHA_SALIDA ) as rn,
ENTRADA.nro_referencia as id1, SALIDA.NRO_REFERENCIA as id2,
ENTRADA.FECHA_ENTRADA as Start_Date, SALIDA.FECHA_SALIDA as End_Date
FROM ENTRADA LEFT JOIN SALIDA on ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA = SALIDA.NRO_REFERENCIA)

select a.id1,a.Start_Date,b.End_Date
from cte a
inner join cte b
on a.id1 = b.id1
and a.Start_Date< b.End_Date
and a.rn > b.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to identify duplicates, i.e. records having the same `id`, `End_Date` but more than one `Start_Date`. Then place your initial query in a sub-query and use the field calculated by `ROW_NUMBER` so as to filter out duplicates:

```
SELECT id1, id2, Start_Date, End_Date
FROM (    
SELECT ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA as id1, SALIDA.NRO_REFERENCIA as id2, 
       ENTRADA.FECHA_ENTRADA as Start_Date, SALIDA.FECHA_SALIDA as End_Date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA, SALIDA.FECHA_SALIDA 
                          ORDER BY ENTRADA.FECHA_ENTRADA) AS rn
FROM ENTRADA 
LEFT JOIN SALIDA on ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA = SALIDA.NRO_REFERENCIA
WHERE FECHA_ENTRADA < '1/1/2014' AND ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA in 
   (SELECT dbo.ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA 
    FROM ENTRADA 
    WHERE FECHA_ENTRADA < FECHA_SALIDA 
    GROUP BY dbo.ENTRADA.NRO_REFERENCIA 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) ) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1    
ORDER BY id1
```

If you want to keep the record having the *most recent* `End_Date`, then simply change `ORDER BY ENTRADA.FECHA_ENTRADA` to `ORDER BY ENTRADA.FECHA_ENTRADA DESC` in the `OVER` clause.